# django-paypal IPN signals not being received

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-ipn, django-paypal

At the bottom of models.py I have:

```
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import payment_was_successful, payment_was_flagged
import pay

payment_was_successful.connect(pay.paypal_success)
payment_was_flagged.connect(pay.paypal_flagged)
```

I'm using the Paypal Developer IPN simulator and it returns "IPN sent successfully", but the code in `pay.paypal_success` and `pay.paypal_flagged` isn't being executed.

The `paypal_ipn` table is being populated, however I noticed under `flag_info` every row has:

```
Invalid form. (<ul class="errorlist"><li>payment_date<ul class="errorlist">
<li>Enter a valid date/time.</li></ul></li></ul>)
```

I don't know if this has anything to do with the signals not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had the same problem.

Apparently the date format the IPN simulator sends is different from the one the `django-paypal` package accepts.

Head over to `paypal.standard.forms.py` and add the 'new format date' PayPal sends.

```
PAYPAL_DATE_FORMAT = ("%H:%M:%S %b. %d, %Y PST",
                      "%H:%M:%S %b. %d, %Y PDT",
                      "%H:%M:%S %d %b %Y PST",    # note this
                      "%H:%M:%S %d %b %Y PDT",    # and that
                      "%H:%M:%S %b %d, %Y PST",
                      "%H:%M:%S %b %d, %Y PDT",)
```

I don't like this solution, because what if PayPal changes the date string format in the future?

This is actually a caveat of Python's `datetime` object that does not know how to easily convert strings to actual time objects easily.

But that works for now.

Comment: Just a note: this is actually a bug of the IPN simulator! I'm really disappointed by the lack of coherence and the disorder of the PayPal docs, they are truly unreadable, and their test utilities are bugged...

Comment: @amir-eldor I have a similar [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762829), but the table is empty.