# django-paypal suddenly stop recieving signals from Paypal

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, paypal

I'm working on Paypal integration to my Django project using Django-Paypal package.I have successfully configured everything and it was working but suddenly the signals form PayPal has stopped.

What issue can be occurred?

Here's what i have done:

**from view.py:**

```
def payment_process(request):
minutes = int(request.user.tagging.count()) * 5
testhours = minutes / 60
hours = str(round(testhours, 3))
# pdb.set_trace()
# What you want the button to do.
invoice = generate_cid()
userInfo = {
    "name": str(request.user.first_name + ' ' + request.user.last_name),
    "hours": str(hours),
    "taggedArticles": str(request.user.tagging.count())
}
paypal_dict = {
    "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
    "item_name": "Certificate of Completion from Nami Montana",
    "custom": userInfo,
    "invoice": str(invoice),
    "amount": "5.00",
    "notify_url": "https://6fd5e31b.ngrok.io/users/paypal/",
    # "return_url": "https://6fd5e31b.ngrok.io/users/profile/",
    "cancel_return": "https://6fd5e31b.ngrok.io/users/cancel/",
}
print(paypal_dict)
# Create the instance.
form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
context = {"form": form}
return render(request, "users/generateCert.html", context)
```

**from urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
   url('^paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
   url('^profile/buildCertificate/$', views.CertificateProcess.as_view(), name='certificate'),
   url('^cancel/$', views.payment_canceled, name='cancel'),
   url('^done/$', views.payment_done, name='done'),
   url('^process/$', views.payment_process, name='payment'),
]
```

**From signals.py:**

```
def show_me_the_money(sender, **kwargs):
ipn_obj = sender
custom = ipn_obj.custom
# Undertake some action depending upon `ipn_obj`.
if ipn_obj.payment_status == ST_PP_COMPLETED:
    print('Get success signal')
    user_info = ast.literal_eval(ipn_obj.custom)
    if int(user_info['taggedArticles']) > 11:
        # here i need to generate and send a pdf file to the user in a new tab
        pass
else:
    print('Get fail signal')


payment_was_successful.connect(show_me_the_money)
```

> **Update:**  When I have tested it with live IPN sandbox it returns `IPN was sent and the handshake was verified`

---

> Payment is successfully depositing to the PayPal sandbox merchant account, only the signal is doing some problem.

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my experience the paypal sandbox can be pretty slow sometimes. How long were you waiting for the signal? Also In case you didn't know you can also check the recieved ipn calls in django admin which is pretty usesful

Comment: Hi @hwhite4, even in Django admin the PayPal IPN is not coming.

Comment: Alright, how long were you waiting for it? The sandbox is sometimes slow in sending the ipn

Comment: Hi @hwhite4, if you mean waiting for the response then I think I have tested it by waiting even for 2-3 minutes !

Comment: Alright, iv done testing on the sandbox using ngrok aswell where it would sometimes take 20+ minutes to get the ipn, but other times it would be really quick.

Comment: So if it is working sometimes that could be the issue

Comment: so, i think i should wait for a while before making any changes to my source code, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, probably best to wait a bit

Comment: see question's update, please!

Comment: with live IPN sandbox request i have found `Invalid form. (payment_date: Invalid date format Sat Mar 10 2018 18:32:10 GMT+0500 (PKT): too many values to unpack (expected 5))` flag in my django admin. What this mean?

Comment: Hi @hwhite4, I think there's a problem because if the issue was from sandbox then it shouldn't send a signal from IPN sandbox.

Comment: Could be an issue with the form you are sending. Also the way you are passing a dictionary to custom probably wont work. You could convert it to a json string though

Comment: Also this might be worth a read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798206/django-paypal-ipn-signals-not-being-received

Comment: now, I have tested it by removing the userInfo dictionary, but still, it's not working.

Comment: Hi @hwhite4, one another thing I have noticed that, in the console, it shows a warning which says ` UserWarning: This method (or branch) is not covered by automated tests.  warn_untested()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. My application worked and now it doesn't. I tried a lot of things (with python3.5 and not 3.6, delete all .pyc, uninstall and install django-paypa, change port...) It doesn't seem to change any thing.

I was giving up, but I recived all my signals in one time. It was a lot of time after. I tried immediately after and nothing, no signals.

So, for me, the probleme is on paypal's server. They takes time. We have to wait.

I hope my experience helps you :)

> Currently, it works normally for me (11 march 2018 11am). I hope it's the same for you :)

Comment: Hi @Romain, you were right, Now it's working for me too. Thank You,